# Непонятное преобразование

Tags: typescript

Есть инпут:

```html
<input type="number"
  placeholder="От 1 до 1000"
  value = {filterSum}
  onChange = {onChangeSearch}/>
```

Есть состояние filterSum:

```js
const [filterSum, setFilterSum] = useState<number>();
```

И есть функция для обработки инпута:

```js
function onChangeSearch (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        let value: number = e.target.value;
        setFilterSum(value);

        if (value <= 0) {
            setFilterSum(value = 1);
        } else if (value >= 1000) {
            setFilterSum(value = 1000);
        }
    }
```

В функции, на строке: "let value: number = e.target.value;". Тайпскрипт говорит, что "e.target.value" имеет тип строка и не может вписаться в "let value". Каким образом меняется тип заданный в состоянии и как это исправить?

Comment: поле ввода всегда строка, можете ее руками преобразовать parseInt(e.target.value)

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов там может быть и флоат

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов благодарю, добавьте ответ, плюсану.

Comment: для float писали бы "От 1.0 до 1000.0" )

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не может, поле `value` - это всегда строка.

Comment: @Grundy ну да, это я что-то загнул =)